# Ubuntu 12.04 repeatedly freezes (have experienced thrice in one hour)

Tags: 12.04, wubi, freeze

I am having this problem from the time. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. It is installed inside Windows, I don't know if the problem is related to that.

I am experiencing this sudden freezing/hanging, especially when I am using Firefox. When it freezes no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>  will work and no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> works. This is becoming a very bad problem for me.

Please help me solve this. I believe if I keep on directly restarting the computer, my computer may get damaged any time.

Comment: As a side-note. To reboot Linux the magic works with Alt + SysRq not with Ctrl.  Read on here with a [Guide to REISUB](http://kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VMware or any other software to run Ubuntu inside Windows?
If that is the case it is a common problem occurred to everyone who have less configuration Computers. It is recommended to upgrade hardware when running OS in OS.

Comment: I have used Wubi to install it

Comment: It's okay. What's your system configuration? Add a screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

Which virtual management software are you running and do you have this option enabled in your bios?

One thing you could do is start firefox from the command line of an open shell like konsole while logging the screen. That way when it crashes you could check out the log and see the error from when it's freezing. It will give you a clue.

But without more information on your configuration it's hard to speculate further.

Comment: I have used Wubi to install it,